# How to open an .rda file in Examples while documenting function

Tags: r, package, rstudio, devtools

I'm facing for the first time the development of a package in R.

I'm using an `name_file.rda` file for the Examples: it contains a `list` object containing itself several objects (`vectors`, `data.frame` and so on), and it's placed inside the `namepackage\data` folder.

While documenting a function of the package, I write in the Examples the following code:

```
load("data/name_file.rda")
```

but, when checking the package, it gives me the following error:

```
load(file = "data/name_file.rda")
Warning in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file 'data/name_file.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
Calls: load -> readChar
Execution halted
Errore: Command failed (1)
Esecuzione interrotta
```

I feel the problem is with the code I use, or the misselected directory.
I'm programming in Mac, using RStudio. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you in the directory of the package?  Also, why aren't you writing the examples as part of the documentation files (.rd)?

Comment: I'm writing the example in the .rd file, of course. The problem pops out when i check the package.
The currently directory is that of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe solved: correct code seems to be

```
data(name_file)
```

without specifying extension of the file (.rda) nor directory.